# Codable: Process one key manually

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I get JSON from API and most of the keys are decoded out of the box.

Example API response:

```
[
  { "href":"http:\/\/audiomachine.com\/",
    "description":"Audiomachine",
    "extended":"Music for videos",
    "shared":"yes",
    "toread":"no",
    "tags":"creative video music"
  },
  { "href": "https:\/\/www.root.cz\/clanky\/nekricte-na-disky-zvuk-i-ultrazvuk-je-muze-poskodit-nebo-zmast-cidla\/",
    "description":"Nek\u0159i\u010dte na disky: zvuk i\u00a0ultrazvuk je m\u016f\u017ee po\u0161kodit nebo zm\u00e1st \u010didla - Root.cz",
    "extended":"Added by Chrome Pinboard Extension",
    "shared":"yes",
    "toread":"no",
    "tags":"root.cz ril hardware webdev"
  },
  { "href": "https:\/\/www.premiumbeat.com\/blog\/10-apple-motion-tutorials-every-motion-designer-watch\/",
    "description":"10 Apple Motion Tutorials Every Motion Designer Should Watch",
    "extended":"For people used to working with FCPX, sometimes learning Apple Motion can be much easier than learning After Effects. While the two programs are different, there\u2019s certainly a lot of overlap in terms of functionality and creative potential. The following ten Apple Motion tutorials are great examples of just that.\r\n\r\nWhether you are someone new to Apple Motion or a seasoned veteran looking to up your skills, here are ten must watch Apple Motion tutorials.",
    "shared":"yes",
    "toread":"no",
    "tags":"apple apple_motion video creative effects"
  }
]
```

I store the each item in following struct.

```
struct Link: Codable {
    let href: URL
    let description: String
    var tags: String
}
```

which is then decoded with something like

```
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:url!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }

    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode([Link].self, from: data)
```

From API data I use *href*, *description* and *tags*. *Tags* is a bit troublemaker, because I want to use it in code as an Array of Strings, but in the JSON it is retrieved as a String containing all the tags separated by space. As this is my first project, I use to learn iOS development, I have almost no idea how to solve this.

I was able to get close by googling computed properties, so it could be something like

```
struct Link: Codable {
    let href: URL
    let description: String
    var tags: String {
        return tagsFromServer.components(separatedBy: " ")
    }
}
```

, but I have two problems with this solution.

1. I have strong feeling, this closure would be called every time the code access `.tags`. I would rather do it once upon the JSON retrieval and after that just read product of that.
2. I have absolutely no idea how to pass "the original tags I've got from server" / `tagsFromServer` to the closure.

I would be grateful for filling up my gaps in terminology or a nice video tutorial on this topic, also.

Comment: Can you mention the sample response you received from the server in question?

Comment: @Sateesh Added to my question. Ty for pointing out it's missing 

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to write a custom initializer, decode `tags` as `String` and split it:

```
struct Link: Decodable {
    let href: URL
    let description: String
    let tags: [String]

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case href, description, tags }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
       let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
       href = try container(URL.self, forKey: .href)
       description = try container(String, forKey: .description)
       let tagsFromServer = try container(String.self, forKey: .tags)
       tags = tagsFromServer.components(separatedBy: " ")
    }  
}
```

Alternatively you can use the computed property but then you have to add the `CodingKeys`

```
struct Link: Decodable {
    let href: URL
    let description: String
    let tagsFromServer : String

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case href, description, tagsFromServer = "tags" }

    var tags: [String] {
        return tagsFromServer.components(separatedBy: " ")
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I met something like this on the web, but I don't want to write code for the keys which already work. Is there a way to do something like what You mention, but just for the tags? What You wrote probably works, but it introduces code I don't need and I have to maintain.

Comment: I updated the answer with the computed property solution. If you want to map a type to a stored property with a different type you have to write a custom initializer which decodes **all** keys. Decoding only a few keys manually is not possible.

Comment: This is very close to my imagination ;) Wouldn't it be possible to do something like your alternative, but store the `tagsFromServer.components(separatedBy: " ")` premanently?

Comment: No, either you get everything for free or *manually* you have to decode **all** keys.